# TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a code that inputs data into different fields of a website, but only if there is data in the excel cell. this is my code:

```
import openpyxl
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time
def copy():
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.press('c')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
excelWorkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('orderCodes.xlsx')
sheet = excelWorkbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for i in sheet.columns[1]:
    info=sheet['A'+i].value
    pyautogui.moveTo(305, 669, duration=0.25)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.typewrite(info)
    pyautogui.moveTo(295, 702, duration=0.25)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.typewrite('100')
    pyautogui.moveTo(217, 738, duration=0.25)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1521, 515, duration=0.25)
    pyautogui.dragTo(1531, 518, duration=0.25)
    quantity=copy()
    sheet['B'+i]=quantity
```

but i get this error:

```
    for i in sheet.columns[1]:
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why do i get this?

Comment: You should include the whole error traceback.

Comment: sheet.columns is a generator and doesn't support indexing - what do the openpyxl docs say?

Comment: Maybe use [worksheet.iter_rows](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=sheet.columns#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) instead or ```Workseet['A']``` which should return a tuple of rows for the first column. -http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sheet.columns is a generator and you cannot `__getitem__` it. (use [] to get something) Try

```
for i in sheet.columns:
```